# Is an array mirror like

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

I'm trying to compare first and second half of an array. For example: `[3, 7, 7, 3]` , `3, 7` is the first half and `7, 3` is the second half. I tried with nested loops but it haven't worked so far. Here is my code and the question is what is wrong with it?

```
int [] arr = {3, 7, 7, 3};
boolean isMirror = false;

for (int i = arr.length/2 -1; i>=0; i--) {
    for (int j = arr.length/2; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
            isMirror = true;
            break;
        } else {
            isMirror = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (isMirror) {
    System.out.println("The array is mirror-like");
} else {
    System.out.println("The array is not mirror-like");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you copy the array and reverse it. Then simply compare it to the original in a single for loop?

Comment: @Patrick.SE what about `{1,3,1,3}`?

Comment: This is similar to finding whether a string is a palindrome. You can do this with one loop without reversing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one loop and set `isMirror = false` when `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` don't equal:

```
int[] arr = {3, 7, 7, 3};
boolean isMirror = true;

for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length/2; i++) {
    int j = arr.length - 1 - i;
    if (arr[i] != arr[j]) {
        isMirror = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (isMirror) {
    System.out.println("The array is mirror-like");
} else {
    System.out.println("The array is not mirror-like");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you are comparing `7` with `7` and `3` using nested loop hence, `isMirror` will be `false` so remove nested loop and use two variable with single loop

```
boolean isMirror=true;
for(int i=0, j = arr.length-1; i<arr.length/2;i++,j--){
    if(arr[i]!=arr[j]){
        isMirror=false;
        break;// not equal so go out
    }
}
```

Comment: what about odd length arrays?

Comment: @DanielGale as per the logic , the result will be true,if first half and second half are same and the middle element doesn't belong to any half

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a mirror, just one loop needed:

```
set boolean mirror = true;
walk from i=0 (first element) to the mid of the array length (say n/2).

  if array[i] != array[maxlength - i] 
     set mirror = false, and the you may end
```